# How to add a Custom HTTP Header for a page hosted in IIS 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7, http-headers

How to add a Custom HTTP Header for a page hosted in IIS 7.0?

It is possible to add one for a folder but not for a page in IIS 7.0 or I couldn't find out how.

However, in IIS 6.0, you can easily right click on a page and add a custom header via the properties window.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following meta tag to your page

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Where http-equiv and content are variable: http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx

Or programmatically in the code-behind:

```
//C#
Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, new HtmlMeta { HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible", Content = "IE=EmulateIE7" });

'VB.NET
Dim custom As New HtmlMeta
custom.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
custom.Content = "IE=EmulateIE7"
Page.Header.Controls.Add(custom)
```

Comment: My question was via IIS 7.0. It's not possible then?

Comment: Not from what I can see. As far as I know if you need it on page level you would need to specify it using the meta tag on the page either explicitly using HTML or via code-behind by injecting the meta data into the head tag.

Comment: Actually it looks like you can. If you open IIS, go to website you need, click on Content View, select the page you want and right click then switch to features view, your page should then show in the treeview. Click on the page in the tree view and double click on HTTP Response Headers and add your response. Just check to see if it displays in the page when you view the source.

Comment: you can do it page by page in IIS 6.0.

Comment: They seem to say it is possible but I just can't find out how: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753812(v=ws.10).aspx. This is the official documentation regarding the adding of a header http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133(v=ws.10).aspx. If I find anything else, I will let you know. Sorry I can't be of more help :(